# How to login with facebook in swift 2.0

Tags: ios, swift

I created a login with facebook application. At first i go to my profile and i created App ID and  i added the bundled identifier. so, Simply I copied and past into the `info.plist` that was created on facebook with App ID and Bundle Identifier.Then I added `FBSDKCoreKit.framework` and `FBSDKLoginKit.framework`. And i added some codes. The problem is, Facebook login is successfully worked. But When i Press the Button Below error is printed and `FBSDKLoginButtonDelegate` functions not called. My system is Hackintosh Yosemite on Lenovo B460e. For reference please, see single line comments in code. Thanks you in advance.

**Error:**

*2016-08-17 19:51:40.736 Facebook[925:34154] -canOpenURL: failed for URL: "fbauth2:/" - error: "(null)"
2016-08-17 19:51:40.808 Facebook[925:34154] -canOpenURL: failed for URL: "fbauth2:/" - error: "(null)"*

Code i have try

**info.plist**

[image]

**This is my AppDelegate.swift**

```
import UIKit

@UIApplicationMain
class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate {

var window: UIWindow?


func application(application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [NSObject: AnyObject]?) -> Bool {

    FBSDKApplicationDelegate.sharedInstance().application(application, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions: launchOptions)
    return true
}

func application(application: UIApplication, openURL url: NSURL, sourceApplication: String?, annotation: AnyObject) -> Bool {
    return FBSDKApplicationDelegate.sharedInstance().application(application, openURL: url, sourceApplication: sourceApplication, annotation: annotation)
}
func applicationWillResignActive(application: UIApplication) {

}

func applicationDidEnterBackground(application: UIApplication) {

}

func applicationWillEnterForeground(application: UIApplication) {
}

func applicationDidBecomeActive(application: UIApplication) {

    FBSDKAppEvents.activateApp()
}

func applicationWillTerminate(application: UIApplication) {

}


}
```

**This is my View Controller.swift**

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController,FBSDKLoginButtonDelegate {

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    let loginButton: FBSDKLoginButton = FBSDKLoginButton()
    loginButton.center = self.view.center
    self.view!.addSubview(loginButton)

    if (FBSDKAccessToken.currentAccessToken() != nil) {

        print("Hello World!")
        self.fetchProfile() //This function called and name,Id printed when the application opens initially that already logged in.
    }

}

func fetchProfile()
{
    print("Profile Fetched success fully")

    let req = FBSDKGraphRequest(graphPath: "me", parameters: ["fields":"id,name"], tokenString: "accessToken.tokenString", version: nil, HTTPMethod: "GET")
    req.startWithCompletionHandler({ (connection, result, error : NSError!) -> Void in
        if(error == nil)
        {
            print("result \(result)")
        }
        else
        {
            print("error \(error)")
        }
    })

}


func application(application: UIApplication, openURL url: NSURL, sourceApplication: String, annotation: AnyObject) -> Bool {
    return FBSDKApplicationDelegate.sharedInstance().application(application, openURL: url, sourceApplication: sourceApplication, annotation: annotation)
}

func loginButton(loginButton: FBSDKLoginButton!, didCompleteWithResult result: FBSDKLoginManagerLoginResult!, error: NSError!) {

    print("Hola") //This function not called when got name and ID
}

func loginButtonWillLogin(loginButton: FBSDKLoginButton!) -> Bool {

    print("Hello") //This function not called when i log in
    return true
}
func loginButtonDidLogOut(loginButton: FBSDKLoginButton!) {

    print("Ni Hao") //This function not called when i log out

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This has to do with the App Transport Security Settings of your application. Apple recently added extra security measures for arbitrary http loads. Try the following method:

Step 1: Go to your info.plist file

Step 2: Add a new key: "App Transport Security Settings"

Step 3: Add a boolean subkey, "Allow Arbitrary Loads", set it to YES

Step 4: Add a dictionary subkey, "Exception Domains"

Step 5: Add a string subkey to "Exception Domains" with the url causing you the error (fbauth2:/ in this case)

At the end, it should look like this (with your url of course)

[image]

As a side note, the Facebook SDK states that your application should still work, regardless of this warning (since you have added the correct entries to LSApplicationQueriesScheme). Did you make sure to assign the FB Login button's delegate to the receiving controller?

Comment: Yeah bro.Still got that error brother. Also `FBSDKLoginButtonDelegate` functions not called. My bundle identifier is not registered in Apple. is that make this problem?

Comment: Try adding this line after you create your login button:loginButton.delegate = self

Comment: Wow Superb bro! `FBSDKLoginButtonDelegate` function worked after adding `loginButton.delegate = self`. All function worked(fetching email,friends,ID,name). but still that error came.

Comment: Good to hear. After reading more of the FBSDK docs, it seems that you should just ignore the warning. There is no clear way to get rid of it